# Cron job with PHP script sending mail to wrong address

Tags: php, cron

I have set up a cron job on Ubuntu to run a script every minute (for testing), using the command `crontab -u username -e`.

The cron job: `* * * * * /var/www/html/autocron.php`

The PHP script is a simple `mail()` sending, and it works when I access the file through a browser.

And the cron job is running every minute. Allthough it's not "listening" to the email address in the php script. Instead it's always sending the email to `username@domain.com` (*same username as the command for setting up the cronjob*).

Syslog: `Aug 11 09:17:01 v314531-vps postfix/local[2579]: CE5C0C254F: to=<username@domain.no>, orig_to=<username>, relay=local, delay=0.1, delays=0.08/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)`

... why is it sending there, and not to `example@hotmail.com` as specified in `mail()` in the PHP-file?

Comment: Can you post your `mail()` call?

Comment: The mail is sent correctly if I open the file through a browser. Anyhow; `mail("My name <myemail@hotmail.com>", "The subject", 'Message', 'MIME-Version: 1.0; Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' );`